# PushSharp + Windows Phone deep linking on Toast Notifcation

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, pushsharp

When using PushSharp with Windows Phone, I'm sending the notification with a deep link to a view in my app.

```
push.QueueNotification(new WindowsPhoneToastNotification()
.ForEndpointUri(new Uri(endpoint))
.ForOSVersion(WindowsPhoneDeviceOSVersion.Eight)
.WithBatchingInterval(BatchingInterval.Immediate)
.WithNavigatePath("/Views/DetailView.xaml")
.WithParameter("slug", slug)
.WithText1(text)
.WithText2(message));
```

But when the toast appears and I touch it to open the app, the app opens to my default view instead of the requested DetailView.

Shouldn't this open to my DetailView?

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068311/navigation-to-particular-page-not-working-in-windows-phone-toast-notification-us?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a path of "~/Views/DetailView.xaml" instead...

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. I push the path with the ~, but it's coming in on the device with the ~ stripped off.

Comment: @Stuart Yes, it's an Mvx view

Comment: For an MvvmCross app you need to intercept the "special launch" - see protocol start in https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/appstart-in-mvvmcross