# Toast notification disappears after 10 sec in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, toast, mpns, pushsharp

Toast notification disappears after 10 sec,if user does not tap on that and I am not able to get How to handle this, if user misses the notification.

Requirement is that toast should not disappear untill user taps on it.

One way of doing this is to send toast and tile notification at the same time.so that if user misses the toast notification then he may find it on tile.But not able to get how to do it using push sharp.So please suggest any solution for the following :

- How to decide duration of toast notification using push sharp?
- If 1st one is not possible then how to send toast and tile notification together using push sharp?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> A toast notification displays **for about 10 seconds** unless the user dismisses it with a flick to the right. If the user taps the toast, by default, your app's start screen launches. Or, you can choose to specify which screen of your app will launch.

There is no way to override the duration of the toast notification.

Comment: Alright.Thanks for the information.So is there any way to know that whether user has **tapped** on the notification or **missed** it,So that server can send him the notification again and again until he taps on it or Can you please provide any documentation stating that there is no way to override the duration of toast notification?

Comment: You dont have to send the notification again and again to an user... that is anoying... just update your app tile with the number of notifications so the user can see it and acces your app if he/she wants.